# Javascript Check date and run the script

Tags: javascript

I would to run .js script only if the date is between December 15 and January 8 (of the next year) so the script will run for 25 days.

My code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var now = new Date();
var day = now.getDate(); // 0-31 Days
var month = now.getMonth()+1; // 0-11 Months
var startDate = new Date();
startDate.setDate(15);
startDate.setMonth(11);
var endDate = new Date();
endDate.setDate(8);
endDate.setMonth(0);

    if (startDate >= now && endDate <= now) {
        snowFall.snow(document.body);
    }
```

the .js file is located `<script src="js/snowfall.js"></script>`

What's wrong with the code?

My html/javascript code level is very bad, I'm a newbie

Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your condition from:

```
if (startDate >= now && endDate <= now)
```

to

```
if (startDate <= now || endDate >= now)
```

That works as the the dates are always of the same year, so `startDate <= now` works between `15.11.2017 - 31.12.2017` and `endDate >= now` will work between `1.1.2018 - 31.1.2018`

Comment: `if ( startDate <= now <= endDate)`

Comment: @chris as `startDate <= now` is `true` , therefore `true <= endDate` equals `1 <= endDate`, so it would snow since 1970

Comment: Oh boy, I'm gonna try to forget about writing this one, that was bad

Comment: @chris to err is human. Youve just verified the *norobot captcha* ;)